# RoutingDataSource with quartz job

Tags: java, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

I have an RoutingDataSource that use 2 databases. I want to make some of my quartz jobs to use one DB and other jobs the other DB.

I use XML configurations in SPring4 with Hibnernate4.

My quartz beans

```
<bean id="emailJob" class="com.resolution.scheduler.service.quartz.EmailJob"
        autowire="byName" />

    <bean id="emailJobProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="target" ref="emailJob" />
        <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="java.lang.Runnable" />
        <property name="interceptorNames" value="hibernateInterceptor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="uniqueEmailJobDetail"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass"
            value="com.kili.StatefulQuartzJob" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="batchProcessorName" value="emailJobProxy" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="durability" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Then After I bean a crontrigger, so no need to be shown here.

Hibernate Interceptor:

```
<bean id="hibernateInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInterceptor"
        autowire="byName" />
```

Routing DataSource:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.resolution.scheduler.service.DBRoutingDataSource">
        <property name="targetDataSources">
            <map key-type="com.resolution.scheduler.service.DBType">
                 <entry key="READ" value-ref="secondaryDataSource"/>
                <entry key="READWRITE" value-ref="primaryDataSource"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="primaryDataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Possible?

Comment: Yes ! But as you do not say how you currently use the RoutingDataSourse, I can't either say how you should do in quartz !

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for taking interest. Please see the updated question

Comment: How can the quartz job know which database do use, and is it compatible with `DBRoutingDataSource` ? And could you show `DBRoutingDataSource.determineCurrentLookupKey()` ?

Comment: It just contain a ThreadLocal that can be set easily but I 'guess' session starts before I could make any set the DBType , hence taking default DB from routingDataSource.

Comment: It is still unclear at what moment you wire the proxy into the `uniqueEmailJobDetail` bean, and at what moment you decide what database to use. But this structure lets fear that the session will be open too early ... You should explain which jobs will use which database, and the reasons and/or timing of the choice

Comment: Yes, I dont have clear idea on when the session gets started. But the uniqueEmailJobDetail is triggered by a cronTrigger that resides in quartzScheduler, I dont know if this is what you've asked. Sir, can you be available on some chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62611/discussion-between-serge-ballesta-and-sachin-verma).

Comment: In case someone comes to this question and has no idea what to do: The sessions to each database are opened at startup. The switching between the databases needs to be done, before the transactions begin. A switch between databases is not possible during transactions